# Странность при выводе объекта в консоль через console.log()

Tags: javascript

Код такой:

```
function SuperClass() {}

SuperClass.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log('hay');
}

function SubClass() {}

function extend(to, from) {
    if (!(to && from)) return 'Ошибка. Нужно два параметра.';
    for (var p in from) to[p] = from[p];
}

function defineSubClass(superclass,
                        constructor,
                        methods,
                        statics)
{
    constructor.prototype = Object.create(superclass.prototype);
    constructor.prototype.constructor = constructor;

    if(methods) extend(constructor.prototype, methods);
    if(statics) extend(constructor, statics);

}

console.log(SubClass.prototype);

defineSubClass(SuperClass, SubClass);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вывести в консоль после вызова defineSubClass(SuperClass, SubClass), то прототип у SubClass.prototype это SuperClass.prototype (Ничего необычного). Но если вывести до вызова, то SubClass.prototype наследуется от Object.prototype (Тоже ничего необычного), но если прейти через свойство *constructor>prototype>**proto*** то как мы видим уже другой прототип.

Объясните почему так? Мы же попадаем в тоже самое место, но почему-то уже с другим прототипом.

Comment: `SubClass.prototype` это объект, а все объекты в js являются потомками `Object`, консоль вам это и вывела.

Comment: @Doigrales читайте внимательно.

Comment: Подождите, ваш объект `SubClass` имеет прототип родителя `SuperClass`, вы организовали наследование, но что вы ищите в прототипе объекта `SubClass.prototype`?

Comment: @Doigrales Вы можете видеть, что прототипом SubClass.prototype является Object.prototype, а не SuperClass.prototype. Но если перейти через constructor>prototype>proto, то уже прототипом  SubClass.prototype является SuperClass.prototype. Почему так происходит, мне не понятно. И ответ на этот вопрос меня и интересует. Возможно это как-то связано с console.log(), я не знаю.

Comment: Это особенность console.log для объектов. С одной стороны, он может показать вещи которых не было на момент вызова (потому что лезет внутрь объекта в момент клика), с другой не показывать последующие изменения потому что закешировал результат (см синюю i вверху картинки). Верить можно только примитивам.